# cordova ios The executable was signed with invalid entitlements

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I read many post regarding my question but not work

I am developing ios app using cordova.

when i am run app using xcode after adding platform to my project `(cordova platform add ios)` first time it works fine.

After make changes in some file i run `cordova build ios` in terminal and again run in xcode then it gives me `The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.`

Now i remove platform and add again then it works first time...after changing code again i have to remove and add platform again.

I don't know how to solve it.

My provisioning profile and code signing identity is correct and also device id is added to provisioning profile.

Comment: are you using Xcode 7.3 ?

Comment: @Divyesh, i m using Xcode 7.2 and works fine for me

Comment: i am using xcode 7.0.1

Answer (score 0):

@Divyesh Savaliya, Navigate to Build Setting -> Code Signing Section in Xcode and check if you are using any file in code signing entitlements. If yes, try deleting the file name. 
 Also ensure to select proper provisioning profile under Code Signing Section.

Comment: No there is not any file in code signing entitlements. and if provisioning profile is not proper then why it allows me to run the first time? I am sure my provisioning profile is correct.

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya, did u updated Xcode recently. If yes, did u tried restarting Xcode as this solution worked for many